# Tomcat concurrency

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, concurrency

I want to use servlet concurrently.

Of course, There is lots of questions related with this subject, but my servlet still works in sequential.

I'm using servlet with Tomcat8, which uses Jena triplestore (with Apache Jena Lib)

My servlet is called within ajax from html, and return data with `response.getWriter().write()` method.

Each browser is blocked while servlet is running, but it would not matter with concurrent work of servlet I think (because it is each browser's work)

I attach here my server.xml setting:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxThreads="300"
    acceptCount="200"
    minSpareThreads="100"
/>
```

and doGet method:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("Servlet Run");
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String data = request.getParameter("data");
    String[] spdata = data.split("\\|");
    
    String sen = spdata[0];
    String name = spdata[1];
    String id = spdata[2];
    
    System.out.println(sen + ' ' + name + ' ' + id);
    int user = id.hashCode();
    System.out.println("Load Init");
    DialogSystemForTomcat d = new DialogSystemForTomcat(user);
    System.out.println("After Init");
    System.out.println("Sentence: "+sen);
    String rtn = d.runJob(name, sen);
    response.getWriter().write(rtn);
    System.out.println("Return: "+rtn);
}
```

As you can see, I call another Java class within `doGet()` method which really processes my input.

(real process is done within `d.runjob()` method)

It is working sequentially for all inputs now, but I want to work in concurrent for all inputs.

What should I change? Please help.

=========================================

#### After...

I worked to make process as faster as possible.

But I could not make it concurrent.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. It is a complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. It's hard to read, can't be cut & pasted, ... There is nothing to recommend it.

Comment: Looks ok to me - what problem are you having with concurrency?

Comment: Tomcat already spins a new thread for each servlet. If you'd like to process the request async, submit a `Runnable` or `Callable` to a thread pool that you manage.

Comment: @DeepakBala No it doesn't. It uses a thread per *request.*

Comment: @EJP That is what I meant - Per servlet per request.

Comment: I'm not using any thread in code. Thread is just used by Tomcat itself. (when invoking each servlet)

Comment: how many clients do you have while you are testing?

Comment: @ka4eli I tested with 2 or 3 devices

Comment: @DeepakBala That's wrong too. Just per request. Not even that with connection pooling.

Comment: @EJP I don't see how. We're saying the same thing. Requests go to servlets whose threads can be spawned from a pool if one is configured.

Comment: @DeepakBala You've now said three different things. Thread per servlet; thread per servlet per request; and threads owned by servlets. These are not all the same; they can't all be correct; and they can't all be the same as what I said. As a matter of fact none of them is. Your latest version is no better. Servlets don't have threads. Threads read requests, and requests are then mapped to servlets. Not the other way around

Comment: @RoxyEris I don't get it: what do you mean by "make it concurrent"? Create a breakpoint in the `doGet()` and call the servlet twice and watch the threads (in your IDE you can see also the threads and where they are).

Comment: @EJB I've said the same thing which you've misinterpreted as 3 different things.

Comment: @DeepakBala Rubbish. You may possibly have meant the same thing every time, but you certainly didn't say the same thing every time. It isn't clear from any of the statements that you have a good understanding of this.

Comment: @EJP It is implied what I'm trying to say. I don't have to be pedantic about it. Saying `per servlet` and then going on to say that it is indeed concurrent *implies* that. My pedantic perspective on your comment can make it wrong too. Requests are mapped to Servlets, but you failed to mention how and in what model.

Comment: Don't fight here please...

Comment: @DeepakBala Saying 'per servlet' or 'per servlet per request' doesn't imply anything except an error. I don't consider it necessary to describe an implementation of the entire Servlet Specification in a comment, buit I do consider it necessary to avoid obvious errors.

Comment: @EJP So your comment is not an obvious error that encourages the `SingleThreadedModel`. ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each browser is blocked while servlet is running, but it would not matter with concurrent work of servlet I think (because it is each browser's work)

You are mistaken. Servlets are concurrent, except for the obsolete `SingleThreadModel` which you aren't using, and unless they contain synchronized methods or blocks, which this one doesn't, or semaphores, ditto. *Ergo* this code is concurrent, unless the processing in the unnamed class is synchronized or uses a semaphore of some kind.

NB You have an error in the `init()` method. It must call `super.init(conf)`. See the Javadoc.

Comment: I'm using boolean flag within work thread to manage Jena TripleStore I/O... This is problem then? class is not synchronized, but I'm using synchronized method to control flag variable.

Comment: Besides this, logs is written that whole process is sequential (even before Jena works)

Comment: ah, additionally i added async:false within ajax. because ajax does not get returns before servlet is ended.

Comment: @FloxyEris Nobody can comment on code you haven't posted.